# Input golf scores and store in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a website with a Leaderboard for a golf tournament and the idea is to have people be able to post scores for each hole, which will get added to a MySQL database, and then a separate page will display the scores on a leaderboard.  I'm in the very beginning stages, but I'm stuck with having the user enter the scores.

My thinking is to store the scores in a table with columns for 'golfer', 'hole_num', and 'hole_score'.

I currently have this on my HTML for entering a score.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">     
Golfer: <input type="text" name="golfer" />
<br>
Hole Number: <input type="number" name="hole_num" />
<br>
Hole Score: <input type="number" name="hole_score" />
<br>

<input type="Submit" value="Add"/></form>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
include ('db_connect.php');

// Escape user inputs for security
$golfer = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['golfer']);
$hole_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['hole_num']);
$hole_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['hole_score']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO scores (golfer, hole_num, hole_score) VALUES('$golfer','$hole_num','$hole_score')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

// Close database connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

This code works, so when I enter a 'golfer', 'hole_num' and 'hole_score' they correctly get added to the table.  As the data entry form stands now though, the user has to enter 1 score at a time and has to specify the hole number.  What I'm trying to do is to have 18 input boxes for scores displayed so that they can enter multiple scores at once, but I'd also like to have it so that they don't need to enter the hole number.  So basically the hole numbers would somehow be tied to corresponding score input boxes already and then when they attempt to add the data to the db, it inserts golfer, hole_num, and hole_score.  Sorry if this is confusing.  I couldn't figure out an easy way to explain what I'm trying to do.  Let me know if I can clarify something.

Comment: Are the hole numbers fixed? like 1-18? or different?

Comment: They would be fixed... Always 1-18

Comment: please use the updated answer

Comment: do people play golf? jeeez....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a simple way to do that for you.

Actually, this answer gives you an idea how to make it. For sure, you can do it more pretty.

**Note:** I did not test it and wrote it right here.

The form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
Golfer: <input type="text" name="golfer" />
<br>
<table>
<tr><th>Hole Number</th><th>Hole Score</th></tr>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 18; $i++): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><input type="number" name="hole_score[<?php echo $i; ?>]" /></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>

<input type="Submit" value="Add"/></form>
```

The insert file:

```
// Escape user inputs for security
$golfer = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['golfer']);

$values = [];
foreach ($_POST['hole_score'] as $key => $score) {
    $score = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $score));
    if (!empty($score)) {
        $values[] = "('$golfer','$key','$score')";
    }
}

if (!empty($values)) {
    $values = implode (' , ', $values);

    // Attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO scores (golfer, hole_num, hole_score) VALUES $values";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
// Close database connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks... This did exactly what I was looking to do!

Comment: @Baker, I'm glad I could help